# Availability Groups and Partition Swapping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning, availability-groups

Is it possible to use SQL 2012 Availability Groups over two machines and perform partition swapping on the primary machine ?

Answer (score 2):

If database that is being partition swapped is part of Availability Group, parition switch operation will be logged into the transaction log and it will be replicated to secondary replica.